# MongoDB refusing connections on high volume ( 10000 ) inserts / writes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

We are inserting data through a Node.js application and connecting to mongodb using the [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) library. 
Mongo DB is sharded with a total of 5 shards. The node and mongos instance is contained on a quad core AWS instance with 14980MB of RAM. Two shards and the config server are 
contained in a single core instance and the remaining three shards are on a different instance with a single core processor.

We can effectively insert 1000 records concurrently in 9 seconds using a Node.js test script.

For 10000 concurrent inserts, about 2000 of them fail and return the following error message:

```
    [Error: failed to connect to [ip address of mongos]]
```

During this 10000 insert process, the first 5000 or 6000 inserts are successful with no error.
During this time, the CPU usage remains relatively low (13% usage).  Then the CPU on one core jumps to about 75% and MongoDB throws the
error message refusing connections.  After some failures to insert, some writes are intermittently succesful.

We've set ulimit -n to 20000 on linux.  We have passed the poolSize=5 parameter within the insert function in our Node.js api.

```
var responseHandlers = require('./responseHandlers')
    ,schemaValidation = require('./schemaValidation')
    ,mongoDb = require('mongodb')
    ,md5 = require('MD5')
    ,ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

function insert(data, timestamp, response) {
  // validating the data to be inserted
  schemaValidation.validate(data, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      responseHandlers.invalidRequest(response, 2); 
    } else {
      //console.log("opening db..");
      server = new mongoDb.Server(mongoConfig.host,mongoConfig.port,{'auto_reconnect': true, 'poolSize': 5});
      db = new mongoDb.Db(mongoConfig.database, server, {w: 1});
      db.open(function(err, db) {
        if(err) { 
          console.log(err);
          responseHandlers.invalidRequest(response, 2); 
        } else {
          db.collection(mongoConfig.collection, function(err, collection) {
            if(err) {
              console.log(err);
              responseHandlers.invalidRequest(response, 2); 
            } else {
              //going to instantiate document fields
              var time = new Date().getTime(),
              oid = new ObjectID(),
              hash = md5(oid.toHexString()),
                            obj = {'data_utc' : timestamp, 'server_utc' : time, '_id' : oid,    'hash' : hash}; 
                            obj.data = data;
              //inserting..
              collection.insert(obj, {w:1}, function(err, result) {
                if(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  responseHandlers.invalidRequest(response, 2); 
                } else {
                  console.log('Insert successful');
                  responseHandlers.validRequest(response, false, result);
                }   
              db.close();
              }); 
            }   
          }); 
        }   
      });   
    }   
  }); 
}   
exports.insert = insert;
```

Can anyone help with why it would be refusing connections, failing to insert? Why does it work 
for a portion of the inserts then fail about halfway through?

Comment: Are you creating a single server (with a poolsize of 5) for every single insert, i.e. creating 10000 db connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are creating  too many connection in loop. Best will be create a singelton instance of mongoDB Client and use the same object for each update and insert in a collection. 
MongoDB has a limit on the connection pool , default size of 5 connections. Any attempt after that will simply rejected the server, however you can increase the default connection pool size, but doing that is not a good idea.
Another point to note is that MongoDB: performs better with limited number of threads performing concurrent writes. For writes in collection ( with latest driver 3.2), mongoDB performs row level locking on collection. It acquires a lock on 1000 records at a time and slides the lock with the record being updated. So if you put more concurrent threads to do parallel operation, it will eventually wait for lock to be released. Better go for 2 threads for writes or max go to 4 with chunk size of 20k or 40K.

You can think of implement producer /consumer pattern for controlled reads and writes.

For detailed read follow it here : https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this issue you should observe the number of connections that are open in the mongod console.  Based on the code sample you provided you are probably opening a new mongodb connection on each insert.  To correct this try moving the instantiation of your 'server' outside the scope of the control loop that you're using to invoke this function.